# SSRS Reports - Visual Studio 2013 crashes when I add or refresh datasources

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, axapta

I've Visual Studio Premium 2013 Update 4. I use Visual Studio to edit SSRS Reports(Microsoft Dynamics AX -> Report Model) for Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 R3.

When I add a datasource to my report, that I choose for the propertie "Data source Type" the value "Report Data Provider" and then, when I click on 'Query' propertie to choose the table, I've the following message :

[image]

When I go to the event viewer, I just have the following error message without other precisions :

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 12.0.31101.0, time stamp: 0x54548724
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18233, time stamp: 0x56bb4e1d
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x000e6054
Faulting process id: 0x9b8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d21d6238454bc0
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: f10f130f-8955-11e6-80cf-005056bf7b8c
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

And when I try to refresh datasource, I've the following message in the event viewer :

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 12.0.31101.0, time stamp: 0x54548724
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18233, time stamp: 0x56bb4e1d
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x000e6054
Faulting process id: 0x4d0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d21d6382f91e13
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: cd252f64-8956-11e6-80cf-005056bf7b8c
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Can you help me please ?

Thank you

Comment: This isn't really code related. I'd try reinstalling or seeing if you can duplicate the issue from another box. Also make sure you're running VS as administrator. It will say `(Administrator)` at the top if you are.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting following ENV variable :

```
1)Open your System Properties. (Right-click start menu, select System, then Advanced System Settings)

2) Click the Advanced tab
3) Click the Environment Variables button

4) Under the System Variables block, add the following value:
       a.  Variable name = COMPLUS_LoaderOptimization
       b.  Variable value = 1

5) Once the value has been loaded, restart the AOS service.
6) Close any instances of Visual Studio, re-open and attempt building another AX project or report.
```

Reposted from:
https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/axsupport/archive/2015/05/19/crash-or-hang-during-ax-project-or-report-build-visual-studio-2013-ax-r3-cu8

Comment: What does this do and how does it work? Does it have side-effects?

Comment: I can not found any information how this variable works. But there is a official Microsoft post in LCS https://fix.lcs.dynamics.com/Issue/Solution?bugId=3383717 suggesting set the variable.